# Javascript (jQuery) Touch/Swipe Vertical Carousel with Scrolling / Acceleration

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I have looked around for awhile and have found one or two vertical swipeable carousels, but none with acceleration.

Basically, there are say 10 items on the vertical carousel.  If the user drags up and down, it should roll the items at the rate of his finger.  If the user swipes fast, it should go through the items quickly.

Think scrolling a page on any touch device. I would like it just like that acceleration-wise, except instead of a page it's a circular vertical image carousel.  Imagine a slot machine, but you can roll through the items with your finger.

Does anyone know of a plugin that does this?  If not, how would I go about making this myself (I'm currently using hammer.js for touch events, but it's early in my project and if there's a better lightweight touch-event library I could switch).

Thanks.

Comment: http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4
http://cubiq.org/swipeview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iScroll is the right solution, as @Yuri Barbashov said.